# How can I display random activity when click button

Tags: android

I used following code in main activity

```
public void button(View v){

         //Create an intent to start the new activity.
            // Our intention is to start secondActivity
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(this,Activity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
```

How can I display random activity when click button?  Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debugged some codes above because there's an error in setClass().. this one works:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x=rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
switch(x){
case 1:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(),Scrn1.class);
break;
case 2:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn2.class);
break;
case 3:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn1.class);
break;
}
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the name of all your activities in an array, generate random number and get activity corresponding to random generated number. Sample snippet

```
    String[] title = new String[] { "Act1.class", "Act2.class","Act1.class","Act4.class","Act5.class"};

public String getRandomActivity(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);// pass number of elements as parameters
        return title[randomInt-1];//this should return class name

        }

Intent intent = new Intent(this,getRandomActivity())
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assume you have 3 activities:

```
public void button(View v){
Random rnd = new Random();
int x=rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
         Intent intent = new Intent();
switch(x){
 case 1:
  intent.setClass(this,Activity1.class);
  break;
 case 2:
  intent.setClass(this,Activity2.class);
  break;
 case 3:
  intent.setClass(this,Activity3.class);
  break;
 }
 startActivity(intent);        
}
```